# How to find condition on a linear operator $b: g \rightarrow g$ so that $b$ induces a twisted homomorphism on its simply connected Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, integration

Let $G$ be a simply connected Lie group with Lie algebra $g$. Let $b: g \rightarrow g$ is a linear operator. Suppose I induce a map $B: G \rightarrow  G$ from $b$ in following manner:
Let $e : g \rightarrow G$ be exponential map. Define, $B(e^x)=e^{b(x)}$ on the generators or image of $e$ and if $g \in G$ and $g=e^{x_1} e^{x_2}$, then $B(g)= B(e^{x_1})B(Ad_{B(e^{x_1})^{-1}}(e^{x_2}))$, notice that $Ad_{B(e^{x_1})^{-1}}(e^{x_2}))$ is in image of $e$, where $Ad_g(h)=ghg^{-1}$. Now I define $B$ inductively on $h =e^{x_1}e^{x_2} \ldots e^{x_k}$ in $G$ by
$B(h)=B(e^{x_1} B(Ad_{B(e^{x_1})^{-1}}(e^{x_2}..e^{x_k}))$. What should be condition on $b$ so that the defined map becomes well-defined.